# ARC Retain Cycles, Grand Central Dispatch and Closures

Tags: ios, swift

I understand that if you assign a closure to a property such as:

```
var someClosure : () -> Void?
let someConstant : Int = 5
```

And call that closure from its class' init with a reference to self:

```
someClosure = { print(self.someConstant) }
```

Then this will result in a retain cycle, so I should use weak to avoid it.

But I couldn't understand the following code which is from a [raywenderlich.com tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5370-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-1-2):

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
      guard let self = self else {
        return
      }
      self.someFunction()

}
```

Why a retain cycle exists here - since we didn't create a reference from view to closure (i.e., saving closure as a property) but only from closure to self; shouldn't it be retain cycle-free?

Comment: [This may help](https://krakendev.io/blog/weak-and-unowned-references-in-swift) perhaps?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I haven't read this article.

Comment: There is no retain cycle. But sometimes you don't want to keep the class instance alive until the closure is executed.

Comment: Oh, I see; I didn't think about it that way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right and Ray is wrong:

Grand Central Dispatch closures don't cause retain cycles.

You can delete

```
[weak self] in

guard let self = self else {
    return
}
```

Please see also https://digitalleaves.com/blog/2015/05/demystifying-retain-cycles-in-arc/

Comment: _nowhere_ in his post, does he mention what version of swift he's using though...

Comment: It is this tutorial which was published in August, 2018 so I guess, it is swift 4:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/5370-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-1-2

Comment: “Grand Central Dispatch closures don't cause retain cycles.” ... In general, you are correct. The exception is GCD repeating timers, sources, etc., where GCD can hang on to the closure. But in general, and in this case, you are right!